# How to get eBay's BulkMigrateListing() API call to work

Tags: ebay-api

I'm trying to migrate an eBay listing over to eBay MIP NG by using the call [BulkMigrateListing](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/listing/methods/bulkMigrateListing) using PostMan.

From PostMan the C# call is:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/bulk_migrate_listing");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "c6a6a651-6412-4fc6-94fb-4459883e69e5");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer The-User-OAuth-Token");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "JSON-String", ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

where JSON-String is:

```
{ 
    "requests" : 
    [
        { "listingId" : "123456...." }
    ]
}
```

and The-User-OAuth-Token is the token from the eBay developer account suitably authorised.

But the response I get in PostMan is:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorId": 25001,
      "domain": "API_INVENTORY",
      "subdomain": "Selling",
      "category": "SYSTEM",
      "message": "A system error has occurred."
    }
  ]
}
```

Has anyone successfully made a call to BulkMigrateListing?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've found so far:

BulkMigrateListing() is very flakey. From experience, the response.Content might be

```
1. {"errors":[{"errorId":25001,"domain":"API_INVENTORY","subdomain":"Selling","category":"SYSTEM","message":"A system error has occurred."}]}

2. {"errors":[{"errorId": 1001,"domain": "OAuth","category": "REQUEST","message": "Invalid access token","longMessage": "Invalid access token. Check the value of the Authorization HTTP request header."}]}

3. Missing token message

4. {"responses": [{"statusCode": 200,"listingId": "123412958208","marketplaceId": "EBAY_DE","inventoryItems": [{"sku": "ABC-004","offerId": "12347167010"}]}]}
```

If the call works then #4 or #1 is returned.

One way to check is to call https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item/THE-USER-SKU.

Returning data might be:

```
1. {"sku": "ABC-003","product": {"title":"The Royal Wedding Harry & Meghan Commemorative Flag With Grommets 52\" x 31\"","aspects": {"Brand": ["PMS"],"Type": [.......

2. {"errors": [{"errorId": 25710,"domain": "API_INVENTORY","subdomain": "Selling","category": "REQUEST","message": "We didn't find the entity you are requesting. Please verify the request"}
```

If the product has been migrated over to MIP NG then #1 is returned otherwise it's #2.